# SQL query to merge and sum time-periods

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sum

I have a database table containing time-periods and amounts. Think of them as contracts with a duration and a price per day:

```
start      | end        | amount_per_day
2013-01-01 | 2013-01-31 | 100
2013-02-01 | 2013-06-30 | 200
2013-01-01 | 2013-06-30 | 100
2013-05-01 | 2013-05-15 | 50
2013-05-16 | 2013-05-31 | 50
```

I would like to make a query that will display the totals for each period, i.e.:

From 2013-01-01 to 2013-01-31, the first and third contract are active, so the total amount per day is 200. From 2013-02-01 to 2013-04-30, the second and third row are active, so the total is 300. From 2013-05-01 to 2013-05-15 the second, third and fourth row are active, so the total is 350. From 2013-05-16 to 2013-05-31 the second, third and fifth row are active, so the total is again 350. Finally, from 2013-06-01 to 2013-06-30 only the second and third are active, so the total is back to 300.

```
start      | end        | total_amount_per_day
2013-01-01 | 2013-01-31 | 200
2013-02-01 | 2013-04-30 | 300
2013-05-01 | 2013-05-31 | 350
2013-06-01 | 2013-06-30 | 300
```

(It is not necessary to detect that the intervals `2013-05-01 -> 2013-05-15` and `2013-05-16 -> 2013-05-31` have the same totals and merge them, but it would be nice).

I would prefer a portable solution, but if it is not possible a SQL Server will work, too.

I can make small changes to the structure of the table, so if it would make the query simpler to e.g. notate the time-periods with the end-date exclusive (so the first period would be start = 2013-01-01, end = 2013-02-01) feel free to make such suggestions.

Comment: how are `total_amount_per_day` calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start with the full query and then break it down and explain it. This is SQL-Server specific, but with minor tweaks could be adapted to any DMBS that supports analytical functions.

```
WITH Data AS
(   SELECT  Start, [End], Amount_Per_Day
    FROM    (VALUES
                ('20130101', '20130131', 100),
                ('20130201', '20130630', 200),
                ('20130101', '20130630', 100),
                ('20130501', '20130515', 50),
                ('20130516', '20130531', 50)
            ) t (Start, [End], Amount_Per_Day)
), Numbers AS
(   SELECT  Number
    FROM    Master..spt_values
    WHERE   Type = 'P'
), DailyData AS
(   SELECT  [Date] = DATEADD(DAY, Number, Start),
            [AmountPerDay] = SUM(Amount_Per_Day)
    FROM    Data
            INNER JOIN Numbers
                ON Number BETWEEN 0 AND DATEDIFF(DAY, Start, [End])
    GROUP BY DATEADD(DAY, Number, Start)
), GroupedData AS
(   SELECT  [Date],
            AmountPerDay,
            [GroupByValue] = DATEADD(DAY, -ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AmountPerDay ORDER BY [Date]), [Date])
    FROM    DailyData
)
SELECT  [Start] = MIN([Date]),
        [End] = MAX([Date]),
        AmountPerDay
FROM    GroupedData
GROUP BY AmountPerDay, GroupByValue
ORDER BY [Start], [End];
```

The `Data` CTE is just your sample data.

The `Numbers` CTE is just a sequence of numbers from 0 - 2047 (If your start and end dates are more than 2047 days apart this will fail and will need adapting slightly)

The Next CTE `DailyData` simply uses the numbers to expand your ranges into their individual dates, so

```
20130101, 20130131, 100
```

Becomes

```
20130101, 100
20130102, 100
20130103, 100
....
20130131, 100
```

Then it is just a case of grouping the data by the amount per day with the help of the ROW_NUMBER function to find when it changes and define ranges of similar amounts per day, then getting the MIN and MAX date for each range.

I always struggle to explain/demonstrate the exact workings of this method of grouping ranges, if it doesn't make sense it is perhaps easiest seen for your self if you just use `SELECT * FROM DailyData` at the end to see the raw unaggregated data

Comment: Thank you! That was both a fast response and a very nice answer.